# JavaFX - Can't run task again

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, progress-bar, task

Maybe someone will know how to solve this problem cause I dunno. I trying to run my class what extends task, for first time when I try to run this it's running properly (I'm using this for progressBar). When the first operation is done by my task, I am trying next call and it doesn't work, only progress bar is showing initalization msg. Thanks anyway/bw.

Here is code:

Declaration:

```
public class QueryCreator extends Service<Void>{

...
//constructor 
....

@Override
protected Task<Void> createTask() {
 return new Task<Void>(){
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        updateMessage("Init");
        // count is  ;d count of queries
        for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
            String queryString = "";

            ....
            // creating string for query
            ....

            FileSaver.getInstance().writeLine(queryString); // instance of file where i put created queries
            updateProgress(i+1,count);
            int procent = ((i+1)*100)/count;
            updateMessage("Done: " + procent + "" + "/100");
        }

        FileSaver.getInstance().closeFile();
        updateMessage("File created");

        return null
    }
  };

}
```

}

Usage:

```
   ....

Service<Void> QueryWorker = new QueryFileCreator(....);

progressBar.progressProperty().unbind();
progressBar.progressProperty().bind(QueryWorker.progressProperty());

QueryWorker.messageProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal , newVal)- {
    procentLabel.setText(newVal);
});

FileSaver.getInstance().createFilePath( .....// filechooser // ) ; // creating file path via filechooser

QueryWorker.start();

....
```

Comment: @jewelsea that is not the answer

Comment: Can you check to see if there's an exception being thrown, and show the stack trace if there is one? As far as I can tell from your code, you just discard any exceptions.

Comment: Oh, I see Kacper, you edited the code in the question from a Task to a Service.  I removed the duplicate flag as it is clearly different now.

Answer (score 0):

(assuming your program goes out of the for loop in call() method and assuming your update method works correctly) my guess is that your program calls the next task before the previous finished execution. For example the first task updates the progress bar and it updated only in 20% while the second task want to "restart" updating, however it cannot to do so since the first task still working with same progress bar.